# Ckeditor - replace

Tags: javascript, ajax, ckeditor

I'm currently working wit the CKEditor.

I have a form where user can fill data inside the CKEditor. When the user clicks the save button ajax is called. Inside the ajax call I replace the data with the form data. Before the ajaxFormOnSuccess() method I'm trying to destroy all the instances and replacing them again.

The destroy works properly but when I try to add an instance again i'm getting the error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'unselectable' of null
>       at c (ckeditor.js:227)
>       at a. (ckeditor.js:224)
>       at a.g (ckeditor.js:10)
>       at a.CKEDITOR.event.CKEDITOR.event.fire (ckeditor.js:11)
>       at a.CKEDITOR.editor.CKEDITOR.editor.fire (ckeditor.js:13)
>       at a.fireOnce (ckeditor.js:12)
>       at a.CKEDITOR.editor.CKEDITOR.editor.fireOnce (ckeditor.js:13)
>       at Object. (ckeditor.js:177)
>       at k (ckeditor.js:161)
>       at Object.load (ckeditor.js:161)

Here is the code for destroying and adding them again.

```
$('textarea.ckeditor').each(function () {
        var txtBoxID = this.attributes.id.nodeValue;
        var editor = CKEDITOR.instances[txtBoxID];
        if (editor) {
            editor.destroy(true);
        }

    });

    CKEDITOR.replace('GeneralData.TypeOfInsuranceGoods', { autoParagraph: false });
```

Currently just adding a single instance to test it but I'm getting the error(see above).

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Thank you in behave.

Brent